# Couldn't show the current logged in user's details in Asp.NET Core Razor view even after signing in to the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am doing a simple sign up, log in and log out user account using Asp.NET Identity for a Asp.NET Core MVC application. Everything works fine but after I logged in, I wanted to show a homepage with the currently logged in user's name but, I couldn't get to do it. I tried various methods given in other questions related to this but nothing works.

For Example, I tried,

```
var cName = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
return ("HomePage", cName);
```

and I tried,

```
var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var name = user.Name;
```

Here is my controller class used to do this operation,

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Chillbook.Models;
using Chillbook.Models.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Chillbook.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> signinManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<AppUser> man, SignInManager<AppUser> sign)
        {
            userManager = man;
            signinManager = sign;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult SignUp()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SignUp(SignUp user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AppUser newUser = new AppUser
                {
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    Email = user.Email,
                    PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
                    Age = user.Age,
                    Sex = user.Sex,
                    City = user.City,
                    Education = user.Education,
                    Description = user.Description
                };

                //Creating the user
                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, user.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    //getting the current user
                    var cName = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
                    //returning a razor view after sign in
                    return View("HomePage", cName);
                }
                foreach (IdentityError err in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", err.Description);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(Login user)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            //signing in the user
            var result = await signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, user.Password, user.RememberMe, 
   false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var cName = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
                return View("HomePage", cName);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid UserName or Password");
                return View();
            }
        }
        public async Task<ActionResult> Logout()
        {
            //logging out the user
            await signinManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

And my startup class section for identity,

ConfigureServices method:

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:IdentityConnection"]));
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Configure method:

```
app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Could you please post more details codes which is related with the startup.cs identity setting?  Normally, we could directly get the user name by using `User.Identity.Name` in controller's action.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I just found out that the problem is not in getting the username but the sign and sign out process itself. I couldn't get the username because I think there is a problem with sign in and sign out operations. I just don't know what it is. I am new to this. Can you help me find out what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using MVC Core 3, you can do the following directly in the Razor View

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

Show logged in User

```
@UserManager.GetUserName(User)
```